# Issues connecting to a Firefox browser on a Windows desktop via remote debugging

Tags: firefox, remote-debugging, console.log, firefox-developer-tools

The company I'm working at has 'terminals' in various locations, which are used by employees to use a web-based control panel. These terminals are just Microsoft Windows with Firefox installed.

The problem I'm running into right now is one of the terminals is having intermittent issues using the web-based control panel via Firefox, and by the time I get over to the terminal to try and debug it, its already resolved itself. And I can't replicate it at all anywhere else.

I see Firefox has a 'remote debugging' feature, which if that gives me the ability to view the console and networking data of Firefox running on a remote desktop, then that would help immensely! But I can't seem to find much out there regarding connecting to a remote Firefox instance on a separate desktop. Most of the articles/videos show how to connect to a mobile device.

So, is the *Remote Debugging* feature something that I could use for this? Or is it for mobile development only? And if it is *only* for mobile development, then does anyone have any recommendations for anything that would allow me to remotely view the networking/console data?

I thought about enabling the **Enable persistent logs** feature in the browser settings, but I think that leaving that open to connect all of that data for days (possibly) would slow down the browser itself. But if that ends up being the only "solution", then I'll do it. I just want to check out any other possible methods.

Answer (score 0):

As [described on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_Desktop), remote debugging of a Firefox desktop browser is possible, as well, though **only on the same machine**.

That means, it only allows to debug one Firefox instance (or another browser like Google Chrome) from within another Firefox instance on the same machine.

*Enable persistent logs* allows to persist the console log and network request log across page navigations, but also just as long as the DevTools are open.

So, you can either:

1. set the *Enable persistent logs* option and tell the employees to open the DevTools once they experienced an issue.
2. tell the employees to open the DevTools once the experience an issue and make a screenshot of them or select everything inside the console, copy the contents and save them somewhere else.
3. connect yourself to their machine immediately after they experienced an issue.

Unfortunately all three solutions depend on the employee to take immediate action on issues.